# Random number grid 4 x 6 Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, numbers

I am very new to Python 3 and want to generate a random grid 4x6 numbers.
I've tried various ways, but end up with it printing on new lines, or printing 4x6 the same numbers on each row etc.

Some examples of code (I tried lots of various ways, but I have to retype them because I am using a virtualbox with linux to run the Python:

```
import random

def grid_maker(h,v):
 for y in range(1, 5):
  x = random.randint(1, 100)
  grid = [[str(x) for _ in range(v)] for _ in range (h)]
  grid[0][0] = "o"
  return grid
print ('\n'.join(''.join(row) for row in grid_maker(6,5)))
```

output

```
o85858585
8585858585
8585858585
8585858585
8585858585
8585858585
```

desired output

```
82 2 30 9 
45 65 54 14
23 4 32 42 
8 84 40 80
43 23 5 62 
23 43 3 5
```

Another example

```
for t in range(1, 5)
 i = random.randint(1, 100)
 grid = [[i], [i], [i], [i]]
 from pprint import pprint
 pprint(grid)
```

output

```
[[100], [100], [100], [100]]
[[1], [1], [1], [1]]
[[80], [80], [80], [80]]
[[12], [12], [12], [12]]
```

desired output

```
[[34], [12], [2], [15]]
[[64], [34], [53], [4]]
[[35], [34], [61], [33]]
[[34], [55], [64], [23]]
```

Another example

```
ar = []
    for t in range(1, 5):
     i = random.randint(1, 100)
     ar.append(i)
    for t in range(1, 7):
     for i in range(1, 5):
      print(ar[t-1], end='')
```

But this prints out `585858585555555559595959343434342222222288888888root@root:/home/user#`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generate only one random number in the first example:

```
import random
def grid_maker(h, v):
    return [
        [str(random.randint(1, 100)) for _ in range(v)]
        for _ in range(h)
    ]
print ('\n'.join(' '.join(row) for row in grid_maker(6, 5)))
```

For the second:

```
import random
ar = [
    [[random.randint(1, 100)] for t in range(1, 5)]
    for i in range(1, 5)
]
for row in ar:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You only call random once each time in the loop so keep using the same value, call it in the list comp:

```
def grid_maker(h,v):
   for y in range(1, 5):
      # add call to list comp to get a new number each iteration
      grid = [[str(random.randint(1,100)) for _ in range(v)] for _ in range (h)]
   grid[0][0] = "o"
   return grid
print ('\n'.join(' '.join(row) for row in grid_maker(6,4))

o 23 47 30 
25 21 32 28
26 76 71 14
54 15 94 77
50 50 29 62
59 92 60 57
```

If you don't want the `"o"` then don't add it just remove the `grid[0][0] = "o"`

The first loop is also redundant you keep  creating new lists but only returning one:

```
def grid_maker(h, v):
    return [[str(random.randint(1, 100)) for _ in range(v)] for _ in range(h)]
```

We can also just do it all in the fucntion:

```
def grid_maker(h, v):
    return '\n'.join(' '.join(row) for row in  [[str(random.randint(1, 100)) for _ in range(v)] for _ in range(h)])

print(grid_maker(6, 4)) # 6,4 not 6,5

26 96 50 46
4 57 50 80
36 24 23 66
71 33 44 15
54 15 77 54
52 99 60 99
```

To print lists of lists the same logic applies, you need to call randint each time:

```
for t in range(6):
    print([[random.randint(1,100)], [random.randint(1,100)], [random.randint(1,100)], [random.randint(1,100)]])

[[90], [57], [21], [11]]
[[84], [80], [100], [47]]
[[25], [37], [87], [97]]
[[78], [90], [100], [74]]
[[96], [83], [59], [2]]
[[83], [19], [90], [4]]
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, the first part worked, but Christos posted both parts, and the second part inside the [ ] [ ] is cleaner in his answer. Don't need to call random randint 4 times, this way, if I would want to expand it, I would have to place random randint 100 times for example. + for the first part tho. Thanks

Comment: @F4LLCON, the whole idea of the answer is to explain you must call the function each time obviously you would do it in a loop for an arbitrary amount of calls